# Flash Form Input Text Is not formatting Correctly

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have this flash form and it was functioning fine a minute ago,  when you go to contact us and click contact us you will see the form only inputs in all caps and for some reason it will not let you type every letter it is driving me insane.  Any help is appreciated.

http://dnacreatives.com/mli2/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just upgrade your Flash?  CS5 has some really nasty typography bugs in it.

You need to select your font and then embed it, and add the font you want to use in the embed dialog and give it a name... it will show up with an * in the list.
Check the box next to all 92 glyphs, so that you embed all the chars.

Now after you close the dialog, find the * font in the list of fonts and use IT rather than just the regular font and use anti-alias for animation (or readability) from the drop down.

Comment: You sir, are my savior.  I should have wrote this before I smashed my keyboard.  I'm not even joking, I broke the little stand to make it tilt up...... THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: :) you're most welcome... I recall being pretty furious about it as well.